# Enemies Path Issue

Tags: java, libgdx

Hello i'm a little embarrassed with a problem i can't fix by my own for since hours.
I made an algorithm to move enemies point by point, it works fine when the path going from left to right.
However when the path go from right to left the enemy jump immediately to the next point, but only when the point is under the previous, when the next point is above the previous the program works as expected.

I have no idea what cause this problem.
I hope someone could help me I would be grateful.

```
public void update (float dt) {
    if (play) {

        angle = (float)Math.atan2(path.get(waypoint).y - positon.y, path.get(waypoint).x - positon.x);          

        velocity.set((float)Math.cos(angle) * speed, (float)Math.sin(angle) * speed);

        positon.set(positon.x + velocity.x * dt, positon.y + velocity.y * dt);

        if(isWaypointReached(dt)) {
            positon.set(path.get(waypoint).x, path.get(waypoint).y);
            if(waypoint + 1 >= path.size) {
                positon.set(path.first().x, path.first().y);
                waypoint = 1;               
            }
            else 
                waypoint++;
        }
    }
}
```

I have already tried to invert the X-axes without success.

path is an Array of Vector2 which contains the position of every point.

Waypoint the next point.

```
private boolean isWaypointReached(float dt) {
    if (path.get(waypoint).x - positon.x <= speed / tolerance * dt && path.get(waypoint).y - positon.y <= speed / tolerance *dt) 
        return true;
}
```

Tolérance is an integer equal 3.

Here is a picture to be more clear.
[Show Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRur8.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see your problem

```
path.get(waypoint).y - positon.y <= speed / tolerance *dt
```

will return true in the problematic case, try using absolutes

```
Math.abs(path.get(waypoint).y - positon.y) <= speed / tolerance *dt
```